# Turn off Visual Studio Highlight Color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I"m having an issue with Visual Studio. I am working in CSS and HTML, but the program does all this highlighting.

[Here's an example of what I'm talking about.](http://imgur.com/a/AWnlk)

I just want to turn off that highlighting in the common words, brackets, and syntax bracket highlight.

I can't find it anywhere in the Tools -> Options section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Web Essentials installed, this is what is causing the issue. Still looking into the specific area.

Answer (score 6):

```
Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors 

→ Brace Matching (Rectangle)
→ CSS Keyword, etc.
→ Find Match (Highlight)
→ Highlighted Reference
```

[image]

**To turn off syntax highlighting *completely***, you can assign another editor, like *Script Editor* to the `css` extension (this will also disable all CSS recognition):

```
Tools → Options → Text Editor → File Extension
```

[image]

Comment: I just did that and it did not change the highlight in the CSS.

Comment: Perhaps there's something with my version of Visual Studio. It still won't let me adjust it...Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's the **"HTML Razor Code Background"** item (I found it by going down the list one by one). I changed the **"Item background"** to **black**, and it looks very nice, having got rid of the gray highlighting, which was, sorry to say it, very annoying.

The steps are the same as listed by Mark Cidade above:

```
Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors
```

[image]

The following picture is the result, which is only a screenshot and is very nice already. The real thing is much nicer.

[image]